# Getting the rows which are in table1 but not in table2

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables like,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[entry]
(
   [id] [int] NULL,
   [service] [int] NULL,
   [sub] [int] NULL
)
```

The values are,

```
id     service  sub
1        1       0
2        1       1 
3        1       2
```

Second table is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[service]
(
   [service] [int] NULL,
   [sub] [int] NULL
)
```

and its values are:

```
service   sub
1          0
1          1
```

In the `entry` table there are 3 rows and in the `service` table are two rows. I want the rows which are not in `service` table but which are in the `entry` table

Thanks

Venkat

Comment: What have you tried? Did you do a search on SO? That's one of the most frequent questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to solve the problem

```
  Select a.id,a.service,a.sub from @entry as a where not EXISTS 
 (select b.* from @service as b where a.sub = b.sub and a.service=b.service)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select entry.id, temp.service, temp.sub from entry INNER JOIN 
(Select service, sub from entry 
Except
Select service, sub from service) as temp ON entry.service = temp.service AND entry.sub = temp.sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variation on the code using except.

```
select id, service, sub
from entry
except
select e.id, e.service, e.sub
from service as s left join entry as e
on s.service = e.service
and s.sub = e.sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    entry.id
  , entry.service
  , entry.sub
FROM
    entry
LEFT JOIN SERVICE ON entry.service = service.service AND entry.sub = service.sub
WHERE
    entry.service IS NULL
    AND entry.sub IS NULL
```